# Porque las personas le dan -1 a mi pregunta cuando la auto respondo?

Tags: discusión, votos-negativos, pregunta-autorespondida

Esta bien subir una pregunta para aportar la respuesta a la comunidad o la idea es solo subir preguntas para que te las respondan otros alguien me puede explicar bien este tema gracias.

Aquí les dejo la pregunta con autorespuesta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tienes un total de 5 preguntas, 2 de ellas autorespondidas, ninguna con negativos.

Comment: porque tuve que eliminar una porque comenzaron a darle -1

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar el enlace a esa pregunta? Algunos usuarios pueden verla aunque esté eliminada. Más allá de que no se pueden saber los motivos por los que alguien vota, y no es necesario que se justifiquen, podríamos ver la pregunta y dar opiniones sobre lo que nos parece bien o lo que se podría mejorar. De todas formas, teniendo 3 preguntas autorespondidas, en la que solamente 1 recibió votos negativos, parecería que es un caso aislado sobre esa pregunta en particular, sin relación alguna a que la hayas respondido.

Comment: te dejo el link @Mariano https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/123582/como-centrar-un-elemento-dentro-de-un-contenedor-son-css

Comment: @Luis No le veo nada que esté mal, nada que a mí me parezca para un -1. Si buscara mejorarla, agregaría un MCVE en la pregunta. Vale mencionar que probablemente ya haya un duplicado de esa misma pregunta (tenía grandes chances de cerrarse como duplicada)...  El usuario que te comentó aparentemente no sabe que se alienta a que los usuarios aporten preguntas con respuesta propia. No le daría importancia. Aunque quizás estaba empezando a responderte y ahí vió tu respuesta, por lo que se enojó. Si vas a responder así, el sistema te permite hacerlo al mismo tiempo que se publica la pregunta

Comment: muchas gracias amigo si vuelvo a hacer una pregunta tomare eso en cuenta en caso de auto responderla gracias por la ayuda

Comment: _«porque tuve que eliminar una porque comenzaron a darle -1»_ No tengo privilegios para ver la pregunta eliminada pero según leo por aquí solo un usuario votó negativo, a todos nos han votado negativo alguna vez en preguntas o respuestas sin motivo aparente, un solo voto aislado no significa gran cosa. Si la pregunta y la respuesta eran útiles y pueden servir a otros usuarios recibir un voto negativo no me parece razón suficiente para borrarla

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo @blonfu. Para dejar registro, era un -1 en la pregunta, -2 en la respuesta. Agregaría una captura, pero creo que eso le corresponde a Luis, si quiere o no que se vea.

Comment: Es que se veía venir una ola de personas nuevas que piensan que esta mal preguntar y después autoresponterte yo cuando apenas llegue pensé que eso estaba mal pues. y mejor la elimine antes de que se sumaran a darle -1 porque otro ignora el tema no se si me entienden

Comment: Por supuesto que estás en tu derecho de borrar la pregunta aunque quizá con el tiempo y esta publicación en meta se hubiesen invertido los votos. También hay varias preguntas similares sobre centrar elementos, no sé si el mismo caso que planteas, aun así yo hubiese esperado un poco para borrar la pregunta